# JSONP-Call with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get a JSON-Call working with AngularJS. Console doesn't throw errors, neither does it work in any way. Anyone able to help with that?

```js
$scope.click = function() {
  $http.jsonp('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&  gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=test&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success(function(data) { 
    var results = data.query.pages;
    angular.forEach(results, function(v,k)  {
      $scope.articles.push({title: v.title, body: v.extract})
    })
  })
  .error(function () {
    alert("error");
  })
};
```

Comment: Console $scope.articles and check

Comment: i have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5wjq0ox/) with above code, but no issue there.

Comment: Maybe an issue with the environment I work with then? http://codepen.io/tbswnzl/pen/Opymrz cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From the angular documentation
You can no longer use the JSON_CALLBACK string as a placeholder for specifying where the callback parameter value should go.

```
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&  gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=test";
$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

$scope.click = function() {
  $http.jsonp(url, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'})
  .success(function(data) { 
    var results = data.query.pages;
    angular.forEach(results, function(v,k)  {
      $scope.articles.push({title: v.title, body: v.extract})
    })
  })
  .error(function () {
    alert("error");
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Much appreciated! Unfortunately it still doesn't do anything. I replaced the parts in the success and error functions with alert("working"); and alert("error");. Shouldn't it bring up one of the messages now either way? It simply doesn't do anything ... thanks!

Comment: I think I had a typo in the jsonp call.